# How Print functionality in the Report (C#) works? How to print an image using printer shared in network?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a windows service, in which I have written some code to print an image file, the printer which I used is a shared over network(local network). But I was facing the permission issue. The printer is not printing the image. When I tried to print the document in crystal report using the same printer it's working fine.

Comment: Possibly because the user account that the service is running as does not have the printer installed in it's profile, or does not have access to the network resource.

Comment: yes, the service is installed with local system credentials,if i changed the login credentials of service then service can access the printer. Is there any way to solve this? instead of using System.Drawing.PrintDocument any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to run the service with a login that *does* have permission to print.

The other problem is services are not given the same sized UI stack as a normal UI application (since it doesn't have a UI).  So, you may run into problems with printing because the printing methods are generally within a UI framework library (WPF, WinForms, etc...)

Comment: can we use the report to print it? is reports will work on console?

Comment: Crystal reports is just going to use the permissions of the service--since it's running the service's address space.

Comment: Thanks peter.. Any other way to achieve this functionality, i have logged in the computer with my credentials but service is running under localsytem, Is it possible to set the credentials by code? I'm using following code,
`PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerPath;
printDoc.Print();`

Comment: what about using impersonation when printing the document?

Comment: I'm not sure why just changing the service account to one with access to the printer wouldn't be your first choice.  Impersonation might work; but then you have to deal with recompilation one user account changes.  I would start by changing the account for the service to see if that works.  If that doesn't, impersonation won't work either

Comment: @tanya That code should work as long as the service's account has access to the printer...  Unless a service can't print due to the limited UI desktop (i.e. printing is inherently a UI-based activity.  e.g. print progress dialog).